# Adding a webpage in rails for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to add a graph page such that when 'listing/id/graph' is clicked, the graph page of listing id is rendered. This graph page contains analytics of that listing id.

I tried the following:

adding in routes.rb
                `get 'graphs' => "listings#id#graphs"`

```
listings controller 
 def graphs
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
  end
as same as 
def show
           @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Current result: No route matches [GET] "/listings/2/graphs"

Expected result: render graphs.html.erb

Rake routes [image: rake routes]

I'm pretty new to Ruby-on-Rails. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason is that you have missing knowledge of Ruby **and** Rails. Also, it is obvious that you can check out [Routing on Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). You'll see plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is obvious. You don't have a route like: `listings/:id/graph` and you want that to exist. Create that route.

```
  get '/listings/:id/graphs' => 'listings#graphs'
```

This will be tedious, but it'll benefit you greatly to read through this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html before moving forward.